# typescript: traversing through specific data in object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object that look like this:

```
{
    "user_id": "",
    "user_name": null,
    "authorization_list": [
        {
            "Key1": "*",
            "Value": "*"
        },
        {
            "Key2": "*",
            "Value": ""
        },
        {
            "Key2": "dashboard",
            "Value": "*"
        }
    ],
    "is_read_only": false
}
```

I would like to traverse through authorization_list and check every value for each key and the rest of data can be ignored.

Comment: I don't understand fully what you try to achieve but to loop on `authorization_list` you can do `your_object['authorization_list'].map(element => { do_what_you_want });`

Comment: the key string is view and value of that key is permission, so on specific component I would like to search through all keys that match that component and retrieve values that they contain

Comment: `your_object['authorization_list'].reduce((value, element) => {
if(element.key === your_component_name) {
return element.value
}
return value}, null);` this function will return the `value` if the component name exist, `null` if not

Comment: this worked, thank you